# unable to install ubuntu onto formatted hard drive

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have formatted a new hard drive (after partitioning - the format has completed successfully) and am trying to install Ubuntu onto it from a DVD.

I have just downloaded the latest .iso file, which I have burned onto a disk.  It has not burned as one single .iso file, but as the separate files/directories as per instructions here:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD?_ga=2.162085044.907860742.1506009408-1494263488.1506009408

The files however are different than the ones shown on here ("here" being the instruction page above).  I am missing most of the individual files, including the start files.  I have all the directories.

The machine will boot fine from DVD drive, as I can boot it with the Windows 98 boot disk, but it will not recognise this ubuntu dvd as being bootable.  And if I boot with the Windows 98 boot disk, then change disks, it just whines at me that A drive is not accessible - even though I'm on the C: or E: and not trying to do anything with the A: drive..

It looks fine to me on my windows machine when I view the contents.

This is a screenshot of the files on the DVD:

[image: This is a screenshot of the directory on the DVD]

As you can see, there are several files just missing.  I've downloaded the .iso file again, but they simply aren't there.

Anyone know what I can do to install it?

Comment: The images in the linked tutorial are old and different from what we have today. The purpose is to illustrate what happens when users burn it the wrong way and I agree, yours seems fine and it *should* boot. **However**... Windows 98?!? That machine is perhaps too old to support any current Linux (and using Windows 98 in 2017 is beyond surreal, I hope you never ever even try to connect it to the internet, for your own sake and everybody else's).

Comment: A correction to the above (stupid me, really stupid): **Any machine originally with Windows 98 is 32-bit** but you downloaded and burned the 64-bit version. That, of course, won't boot in 32-bit PCs. Please obtain the 32-bit ISO.

Comment: Oh no - it has never had Windows 98 on it - that's just the boot CD I was using to boot it into DOS.  So you have a formatted hard disk with nothing on it, and I use that boot disk to boot the machine.  The machine has the necessary specs for ubuntu.   Sorry if I confused you with that.

Comment: What are those specs exactly? (And, if newer, USB instead of DVD is preferable and much faster).

Comment: The specs are on this page - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements?_ga=2.199192743.907860742.1506009408-1494263488.1506009408

Comment: I have just tried with the 32 bit as you suggested anyway, and so far it seems to be installing.  So - not sure why the 64 bit one won't, as the machine is only 2 years old.  Oh well.  *shrugs*.  Many thanks for your help.  If you put your suggestion in an answer MichaelBay, I can accept it.  Many thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I won't make an answer out of this because it would be wrong. If it's a 64-bit machine it should boot and install the 64-bit Ubuntu. Perhaps the other burn went wrong somehow?...

Comment: Oh ok.  Well, thanks for your advice anyway.  Much appreciated.  I'll fight some more with it tomorrow.  :)